# Restaurar banco PostgreSQL em C#

Tags: postgresql

Criei um .bat para realizar a restauração de um banco de dados em PostgreSQL e funcionou perfeitamente utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
set PGPASSWORD=postgres123

C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_restore.exe -i -h localhost -p 5432
-U postgres -c -d dbrestore -v D:\bkp.backup
```

Agora quero executar um bat para fazer isso em C#. estou executando essa função:

```
static void Restore()
{
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", clsConfigBanco.PASSWORD);
  const string exe = @"C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_restore.exe";
  const string arg = "-i - h localhost - p 5432 - U postgres - c - d dbrestore - v D:\bkp.backup";

  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.FileName = exe;
  startInfo.Arguments = arg;

  try
  {
      using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
      {
          exeProcess.WaitForExit();
      }
  }
  catch
  {
       // Log error.
  }
}
```

O Problema é que essa função nem executa o bat. apenas pisca e desaparece. como consigo fazer uma função para executar esse bat? e eu tenho que gerar ele em tempo de execução pois nem sempre as variaveis vão ser as mesmas

Comment: só uma observação: nesse contexto, não há mais .bat. o bat é um arquivo de lotes, com vários comandos apenas. O título correto seria: "Restaurar banco postgresql em c#"

Comment: No final da string args? acabei de fazer isso e ele não me gerou nenhum arquivo.txt

Comment: Estranho, quando eu executo System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Caminho+""+"Restore 2.bat") funciona perfeitamente, porém quando eu tento criar ele não funciona

Comment: Certo, tentei fazer desse método e não funcionou. teria como eu colocar um comando pause será? para ver o possivel erro. mas o erro deve ser na execução do processo e não no comando eu acho

Comment: Vou tentar agora um momento, eu deixo o Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", clsConfigBanco.PASSWORD); na primeira linha ?

Comment: também não deu certo

Comment: verifica, que nos argumentos, não tem o @ antes da string, pode estar dando problema na \ do caminho do arquivo. Não apresentou erro pq \b é um caractere especial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na seguinte linha:

```
const string arg = "-i - h localhost - p 5432 - U postgres - c - d dbrestore - v D:\bkp.backup";
```

não foi colocado `@` antes da string, o que faz com que `\` seja um caractere especial e o compilador não apresentou erro pois `\b` é um caractere especial.

Você pode solucionar isso, colocando o `@` antes da string, ou utilizando `\\` no lugar de `\`

Você também tem que tirar o `using`:

Segue código:

```
static void Restore()
{
  Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", clsConfigBanco.PASSWORD);
  const string exe = @"C:\Progra~1\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_restore.exe";
  const string arg = @"-i - h localhost - p 5432 - U postgres - c - d dbrestore - v D:\bkp.backup";

  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.FileName = exe;
  startInfo.Arguments = arg;

  try
  {
      Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);
      exeProcess.WaitForExit();
  }
  catch
  {
       // Log error.
  }
}
```

como postei em outra questão, utilizo o `psql` para executar o restore. Aqui, fiz o seguinte código e funciona perfeitamente:

```
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", senha);
        const string exe = @"C:\Progra~2\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\psql";
        const string arg = @"-U postgres -d db_banco -f D:\Backup\postgresql.dumpall";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = exe;
        startInfo.Arguments = arg;

        Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);

        exeProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Mesmo colocando o @ não funcionou, ocorre o mesmo erro :/

Comment: tem o using também. Remova-o. aqui testei e funciona

Comment: Alterei o Progra~1 para Program Files, adicionei o @ e removi o using e acabei de depurar o valor da variavel exe consistem em `"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\bin\\pg_restore.exe"` e em args `"-i - h localhost - p 5432 - U postgres - c - d dbrestore - v D:\\bkp.backup"`. Adicionei o valor do exe ao explorer e ele me abriu o restore. mas mesmo assim não funciona. será alguma incompatibilidade com o WPF? mas acho que não pois estou fazendo o backup e está funcionando normalmente

Comment: alterei a resposta, colocando o código que utilizei aqui e funciona perfeitamente

Comment: o plsql não é compativel com o tipo backup no qual estou utilizando. apenas o restore. caso eu utilize o plsql ele irá dizer que os comandos estão inválidos

Comment: Com o plsql funcionou perfeitamente. vou tentar alterar o tipo então do backup dumpall. você sabe se tem muita diferença entre backup e dumpall?

Comment: sei q tem o dumpall que realiza o dump de todas as bases do sgdb, o dump que faz o dump da base informada, e o psql que utilizo pra restaurar. sobre `backup` ou `pg_restore` eu não sei falar =/

Comment: Você sabe me falar se existe algum jeito para o usuario não poder fechar o processo que está sendo executado?

Comment: deixe ele oculto... é algumas das propriedades do `ProcessStartInfo `

Comment: Obrigado pela Ajuda