# Restaurar backup no fomato Plain

Tags: postgresql

Como restaurar um backup PostgreSQL no formato **Plain** ??

O servidor é Windows.

Ja tentei no SQL Shell, mas me parece que não encontra o arquivo.

`banco=# < C:\pasta_do_arquivo\bkp_plain.backup
Erro: Comando invalido \pasta_do_arquivo.`

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250305/69359 aqui tem uma questão parecida que pode utilizar. Obs. O -1 não é meu, mas pode melhorar sua pergunta.

Comment: sempre uso os formatos custom e tar, mas recebi um backup e descobri que foi feito no formato Plain, e não acertei usa-lo. Ate a restore no pgAdmin não tem este formato mas no backup sim.

Comment: é o mais simples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line / https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/backup.html

Answer (score 0):

Para restaurar com o formato Plain, pelo que entendi, precisa ser pelo SQL Shell(psql).

1) Entre com o usuario [postgres] e no banco [postgres]

2) Criar banco a ser restaurado:

```
create database testes;
```

3) Conectar ao banco a ser restaurado:

```
\c 'dbname=testes user=postgres'
```

4) Iniciar restauração indicando o local do backup:

```
\i 'c:\\pasta_bkps\\testes.backup'
```